# Links for websites that were used to show miners signaling support for segwit

Tags: mining-pools, segregated-witness, bip

Anyone got links for websites that were used to show miners signaling support for segwit? or screenshots?

Also wanted to confirm if my assumptions are correct about the whole thing:

1. Initially [BIP 9](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0009.mediawiki) was supposed to activate segwit but there was lot of controversy
2. [BIP 91](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0091.mediawiki) was proposed but again controversy
3. [BIP 148](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0148.mediawiki) was proposed and everyone agreed to activate BIP 91
4. Finally [BIP 141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki) was used to activate segwit

Comment: That's not really correct. All of those BIPs were involved. BIP 9 described the concept of using version bits to signal for activation. The segwit consensus rule BIP141 used BIP9 for activation. BIP148 proposed activating BIP141 without waiting for its BIP9 signalling, after a certain date. Before that could happen, BIP91 proposed a new rule (with reduced signalling requirements) that once activated, would force miners to signal for BIP141's BIP9 activation. That also happened: BIP91 got signalled for, which activated, and miners then followed up by signalling for BIP141, which activated.

Comment: Thanks @PieterWuille for the details

Answer (score 1):

On [Pieter Wuille's website](http://bitcoin.sipa.be/versions.html) there are graphs about the Bitcoin network.

These feature graphs of the block version (used for version bit signaling) across time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay found one website and got relevant images in web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20170722094209/https://www.xbt.eu/

[image: xbt-eu]